# Using a specific API with Python

Tags: python, api

I am very new to Python (and relatively new to programming) and would appreciate any help.

How would I use the following example link to download the supplied information using Python.

https://url.com/InfoService/GetFlightByFlightNum?board={BOARD}&flightNum={FLIGHTNUM}

Method: GET

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to access APIs from python is using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) library

You can quickly install it with `pip install requests`

Then you can do that for your example:

```
import requests

payload = {'board': {BOARD}, 'flightNum': {FLIGHTNUM}}
r = requests.get('https://url.com/InfoService/GetFlightByFlightNum', params=payload)

# print the response result
print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin library urllib2.

Python 2 documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Python 3 documentation: http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html

Here are some examples: [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)